# Argument for template template parameter appears to be a non-template type

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

The following code produces an error, but I'm not sure why this is the case.

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template <typename T, template <typename...> class F, typename = void>
struct tuple_subtype_apply {
    using type = typename tuple_subtype_apply<T, F,
        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<T>::value>>::type;
};

template <typename T, template <typename...> class F, std::size_t... Is>
struct tuple_subtype_apply<T, F, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
    using type = F<typename std::tuple_element<Is, T>::type...>;
};

template <typename... Args>
using true_t = std::true_type;

template <template <typename...> class Fn, typename... Ts>
struct prepend
{
    template <typename... Args>
    using fn = Fn<Ts..., Args...>;
};

template <typename T, typename Tup>
using test = typename tuple_subtype_apply<Tup,
    prepend<true_t, T>::fn>::type;
```

The error produced: (clang -std=c++1z)

```
<source>:29:24: error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for 'template<class T, template<class ...> class F, class> struct tuple_subtype_apply'
  prepend<true_t, T>::fn>::type;
                    ^
<source>:29:24: note:   expected a class template, got 'prepend<true_t, T>::fn'
```

Manually substituting the template parameters for `test` compiles without errors (e.g. `typename tuple_subtype_apply<std::tuple<int, int>, prepend<true_t, int>::fn>::type`). Shouldn't prepend::fn be a templated type?

Answer (score 2):

Since `prepend<true_t, T>::fn` is a [dependent name](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name#The_template_disambiguator_for_dependent_names), `template` needs to be added before `fn`.

```
template <typename T, typename Tup>
using test = typename tuple_subtype_apply<Tup,
    prepend<true_t, T>::template fn>::type;
```